# Convert Python Dict to jqtree structure

Tags: python

In one of my projects I am trying to convert the following python dict

```
{
'node1' : 
    {
        'child1': {}, 
        'child2':{}
     }, 
'node2': {'child3': {}
    }
}
```

to the following structure,

```
var data = [
{
    name: 'node1',
    children: [
        { name: 'child1' },
        { name: 'child2' }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'node2',
    children: [
        { name: 'child3' }
    ]
}
];
```

This format is used by [jqtree](https://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/).
Can anyone suggest the best way for this. Since the result data structure does not contain 'node1' as key, I am not sure how to insert next level data into it.

Comment: You can do it iteratively. Create a function that gets the python dict and a list of the desired jqtree keys (e.g. "name", "children"). For each key of the python dict start building the jqtree structure. Then get the values of each key and continue building the structure iteratively until no more values are assigned to this key. Then move on the next key until no keys are left. What have you tried?

Comment: @Tasos , thank you for your time. I tried few recursive options, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick recursive function that will work for your example. If the children contain other types (lists, etc.) instead of purely being a nested-dict structure, you may need to make some modifications:

```
def jqtree_from(data):
  jq = []
  for key, value in data.items():
    node = {'name': key}
    if value:
      node['children'] = jqtree_from(value)
    jq.append(node)
  return jq
```

Example:

```
>>> d = # your example here
>>> jqtree_from(d)
[{'name': 'node1', 
  'children': [{'name': 'child1'}, 
               {'name': 'child2'}]}, 
 {'name': 'node2', 'children': [{'name': 'child3'}]}]
```